# Stripe API payload Format issue

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe API in my python application therefore not using python stripe library instead using stripe API endpoints only. The issue I'm facing is with the payload especially when sending array or nested dictionary like below:

```
def create_payment_intent(api_key, authorized_amt):
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}
payload = {
    "amount": authorized_amt,
    "currency": "usd",
    "capture_method": "manual",
    "payment_method_types": ["card"],
}
res = requests.request(
    "POST", url=PAYMENT_INTENT_URL, data=payload, headers=headers
)
payment_intent = res.json()
return payment_intent
```

when I run this I get error below:

`{'error': {'message': 'Invalid array', 'param': 'payment_method_types', 'request_log_url': 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_r9TIQ1wnYF8Gi4?t=1699501606', 'type': 'invalid_request_error'}}`

But when I change its format like below it works:

`"payment_method_types[]": "card"`

This is same for objects also I will have to send like below to make it work:

```
  payload= {
   "card[number]": 4242424242424242,
    "card[exp_month]": 12,
    "card[exp_year]": 2034,
    "card[cvc]": 999
   }
```

why is it like this?

Comment: can you post the log of the error returned from the request_log_url?  And the url you are trying to POST the data too?  I looked at the docs and sometimes they do have oddly structured keys.  Also confused why you don't use their (Stripe) python SDK.  Have you read the docs? https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=curl

Comment: the log says 'Invalid Array' that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the data type that Stripe API endpoint expects is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: So there is no workaround it to send it as in json format?

Comment: You can convert the json data to x-www-form-urlencoded before sending it to Stripe API endpoint.

Comment: using urllib library right. Tried that too but gets error.
urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)